# Moving text on wave path with jQuery and stop on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<svg width="100%" height="160px" viewBox="0 0 1098.72 89.55">
    <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M0.17,0.23c0,0,105.85,77.7,276.46,73.2s243.8-61.37,408.77-54.05c172.09,7.64,213.4,92.34,413.28,64.19"></path>
    <text width="100%">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve">*The pictures are not technically selfies.</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        const textPath = document.querySelector("textPath");
        const textPathLength = textPath.getComputedTextLength();
        const duration = 10000; // Adjust the duration as needed

        $(textPath).css("startOffset", textPathLength);

        function animateText() {
            $(textPath).animate(
                { "startOffset": -textPathLength },
                {
                    duration: duration,
                    easing: "linear",
                    complete: function() {
                        animateText();
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        animateText();
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to move text on wave path but its not working. I want it to move on the path so I add it to section on the website. If I try with marquee tag its move but in straight line. I also try many marquee options but the result is not same as I want.

Comment: If understood correctly you want to do something like this: https://css-tricks.com/moving-text-on-a-curved-path?

Comment: This example moving on scroll but I want it like marquee and in loop.  So the text never ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery's [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method can only animate **CSS properties** – SVG's **`startOffset` attribute can't be changed via CSS**.

### Alternative: animate your text via [SMIL animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate)

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg')

// pause and resume
svg.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  svg.pauseAnimations();
})

svg.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  svg.unpauseAnimations();
})
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="160px" viewBox="0 0 1098.72 89.55">
    <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M0.17,0.23c0,0,105.85,77.7,276.46,73.2s243.8-61.37,408.77-54.05c172.09,7.64,213.4,92.34,413.28,64.19"></path>
    <text width="100%">
        <textPath id="textPath" href="#curve" startOffset="100%">*The pictures are not technically selfies.
           <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="100%" to="-50%" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

You just need to add an `<animate>` elements to your textpath and specify parameters duration, initial and final values like so

```
<textPath id="textPath" href="#curve" startOffset="100%">*The pictures are not technically selfies.
<animate 
    attributeName="startOffset" 
    from="100%" 
    to="-50%" 
    begin="0s" 
    dur="5s" 
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
</textPath>
```

Now we can easily pause all animations by calling `pauseAnimations()`

See also ["How to pause and run just one SMIL animation in svg?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498272/how-to-pause-and-run-just-one-smil-animation-in-svg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could do using `UNPKG splitting` script. You need to put the needed path in the CSS variable `--path`. Tweaking the animation will give you different results.

```js
Splitting({
  whitespace: true
})
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --path: "M0.17,0.23c0,0,105.85,77.7,276.46,73.2s243.8-61.37,408.77-54.05c172.09,7.64,213.4,92.34,413.28,64.19";
}

.myText {
  height: 100px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red;
}

.char {
  position: absolute;
  offset-path: path(var(--path));
  offset-distance: calc(var(--char-index) * 1.5rem);
  animation: loop 4s cubic-bezier(.62, .01, .42, 1.01) infinite alternate calc(var(--char-index) * 10ms);
}

@keyframes loop {
  50% {
    offset-distance: calc((var(--char-index) * 1rem) + 40%);
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: calc((var(--char-index) * 1rem));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting@1.0.6/dist/splitting.min.js"></script>

<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
</p>

<p class="myText" data-splitting>Your text here</h1>

<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
</p>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
</p>
```

And even if that is not what you want, you could modify it or use it as a base or inspiration for your actual case of use